# How make a sprite in group create anothers objects and destroy himself?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm starting with *Phaser*, and I need make the follow animations:
A **sprite of car** appear from any side of screen, so, in a specific point another car move in same direction, and another and another, ever with same interval and when this cars be out of screen, they will be destroyed.

For try, I put on sprite, but when car collide with them, another car start the movement. Look the code:

```
var x = 800
var y = 600


var game = new Phaser.Game(x, y, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
var cars;
var next;

function preload() {
  game.load.image('car', 'assets/images/car.png');
  game.load.image('next', 'assets/images/square.png');
  game.load.image('destroy', 'assets/images/square.png');
}


function create() {
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.stage.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";

  // call next car
  next = game.add.sprite(500, 200, 'next');
  game.physics.arcade.enable(next);
  // next.body.checkCollision.right = false;
  next.body.bounce.set(0);
  next.body.immovable = true;

  // destroy last car
  destroy = game.add.sprite(0, 550, 'destroy');
  game.physics.arcade.enable(destroy);
  destroy.body.immovable = true;


  cars = game.add.physicsGroup();

  createCar(null, null);
}

function update() {
  game.physics.arcade.collide(next, cars, createCar, processHandler, this);
}

function processHandler (pointer, car) {

    return true;

}
function createCar(pointer, car) {
  console.log('call next');
  car = cars.create(x, 0,'car');
  car.body.velocity.setTo(-150, 100 );
}
```

But not work, because, with `collision`, the car out of his path and without her, he don't call `collision` or `overlap` callback. Look:

[image]

How I can made this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fully understand your question and problem ... the collision doesnt make much sense at the moment as far as I can see. You should take a look at the examples on the phaser website. You will find good code examples for your case.

To check collisions of the world/screen you can use

```
checkWorldBounds and set it to true.
```